# What is the procedure to test OpenThread for CC2538?

Tags: platform, openthread

The [demo provided at Github for CC2538](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/cc2538) doesn't describe the test procedure. If one follows the procedure described for POSIX (for an older version), then `start` command is not valid.

Though the documentation `help` lists `start` as a command, but it is not a valid command (in cli.cpp).

Can someone guide me through the test procedure?

Comment: Provide the link for the demo on Github for more clarity and reference

Comment: @Tara Wilfred here is the link [link] (https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/cc2538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, its mentioned in `apps` path, which was missed by me.

https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/apps/cli